# Attach to NodeJS process from VS Code skips first statement

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm starting NodeJS outside VS Code

```
node --debug-brk  main.js
```

Here is the code of main.js

```
console.log('Hello from child');
console.log('Hello from child2');
console.log('Hello from child3');
```

When I attach to it using VS Code **attach** configuration debugger skips breakpoint on the first statement.

```
{
    "name": "Attach to Node",
    "type": "node",
    "address": "localhost",
    "port": 5858,
}
```

I'm running VS Code 0.8.0 on  Windows 7. Node version v0.10.33.

I wonder is this a bug of VS Code debugger or an issue with my local environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with VSCode 0.8.0 on older versions (< 0.12.x) of NodeJS. Starting with NodeJS version 0.12.0 VSCode breaks fine on the first line. This will be fixed in VSCode 0.9.0.